# How to read the position value given the cost center

Tags: abap, sap-hr

I want to read the position using this FM `HRWPC_RPT_COSTCENTER_EVALPATH` where the cost center is given.

There are 3 result tables. from which table I can read the position value ?

here how I call the FM:

```
 DATA i_hrrootob TYPE TABLE OF hrrootob.
  DATA w_hrrootob LIKE LINE OF i_hrrootob.

  DATA i_object_tab TYPE TABLE OF objec.
  DATA w_object_tab LIKE LINE OF i_object_tab.

  data i_STRUC TYPE TABLE OF STRUC.

  w_hrrootob-otype = 'K'.
  w_hrrootob-objid = w_orgdata-costcenter_key-costcenter.

  APPEND w_hrrootob TO i_hrrootob.

  CALL FUNCTION 'HRWPC_RPT_COSTCENTER_EVALPATH'
    EXPORTING
   depth                  = 0
      evpath                 = 'KOSTDIUP'
*   PLVAR                  = 01
*   BEGDA                  = SY-DATUM
*   ENDDA                  = SY-DATUM
*   LEVEL                  = 1
    TABLES
      root_objects           = i_hrrootob
      result_objec           = i_object_tab
      result_struc           = i_STRUC
 EXCEPTIONS
   NO_OBJECTS_FOUND       = 1
   OTHERS                 = 2
            .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it by myself.
The result table `result_objec` has the value in the field `stext`, where the `obtype ='S'`

Comment: use SE37 and try it manually before asking... useless question. you took longer to write this post then executing the function manually